# CLion IDE doesn't recognize my C symbols

Tags: c, clion

Just installed the new CLion IDE and wanted to try it.
Wrote a simple C program in a single source file that has 2 functions: foo() and bar(). main() calls foo and foo calls bar.

Tried to find references of both of the funcs and got nothing. Same goes for call hierarchy. I assume I forgot to configure something.

The C file compiles with gcc.
I googled the problem but found nothing helpful.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Is it a new file you added? did you add it also to the CMakeLists.txt, sources of the executable (something like that)? where the default "main.cpp" is.

Comment: Yes. It was added there.

Comment: Sorry for the obvious: did you also reloaded the CMakelists.txt ?

Comment: Yes, I reloaded it. it also marks foo() and bar() functions that never been used.